# Spring cloud stream RabbitMQ interceptors getting message in byte[]

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, interceptor, spring-cloud-stream

I am facing the same issue mentioned in details in the following link:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1686

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the payload type transformation occurs ***only*** when it is known which message handler (method) is going to be invoked and which type is specified as an input. Remember, there are still a lot of things that are in play here -  *routing* would be the best example, since only after routing decision we know which handler to invoke and how to extract type information to perform type transformation

Non of it known at the interceptor level since it is too early, so the general recommendation is to NOT ever rely on payload  when message is in route and instead structure your message as such that any kind of in-route decision could be made based on message headers which are simple types. A good analogy would be a post service which makes routing decisions based on the information provided on the envelope (the mailman does not open your letters to see the payload to make those decisions).
Anyway, a while back I wrote a blog post - https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/26/spring-cloud-stream-2-0-content-type-negotiation-and-transformation. .. have a read as there are more details there.